# Is there a way to normalize the students t dist similarily to the normal dist? And how does it work?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I am wondering if there is a way yo express a $t(0,1,v)$ (Student's $t$-distribution with $v$ as the degree of freedom, $0$ as the mean and $1$ as the scaling parameter) in terms of a $t(0,1,1)$ distribution.
In my math book, it seems like one can claim that (from solution in the exercises) that:
$$
t(0,1,v) = \sqrt{\frac{v-2}{v}} \times t(0,1,1)
$$
Similar to a $\mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma^2)$-distributed variable $X$ can be written as $X = \mu + \sigma Z$, where $Z$ is $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$-distributed.

I could imagine that this has to do with the elliptical distribution properties? Is the statement above true? And how is it proved?

Thanks and sorry for the ugly formulations, I was in a hurry.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Location%E2%80%93scale_family

Comment: But as of my understanding, this is only true in the case when t has the same amount of degrees of freedom?

However, if it holds for different degrees of freedom, where does the invesion in the division-part of the equality above come from?

Comment: Oh sorry I have overlook your parametrization. The transformation can only affect the location-scale parameters, not the degree of freedom. So they cannot be equal in distribution.

Comment: In the textbook to the course, Risk and Portfolio Analysis (Lindskog, Hult, Hammarlid, Rehn), they mention that the Covariance matrix is the same as a constant times Dispersion Matrix. 

In the case of normally distribution, this constant is 1, and for student t, it is given by: v/v-2, then using the fact that both t(0,1,v) and t(0,1,1) are elliptical and spherical, we can in the 1-d case say that:

T(0,1,v) = $\mu+ sqrt(Dispersion Matrix)* t(0,1,1)$ , where dispersion matrix in this case is (1)* (v-2 / v), since Cov. Matrix = v/(v-2) ^Disp. Matrix.

Prop. 9.3 in the same book.

Comment: Did you follow?

Comment: To clarify, the book define the dispersion matrix as wikipedia defines the covariance matrix, i.e. a matrix with the scaling parameters. Thus, in both cases it is 1, giving the result.

Comment: My point is that if $T$ is a t-distributed random variable with degrees of freedom $v$, then you cannot transform it to another $t$ distribution with different degree of freedom by a linear transformation.

Comment: I see, but this is not the answer I needed haha. They seem to use this sort transformation in various exercises, without explicitly stating it.